# Panel in own window?

Tags: c#, window, panel, floating

Is it possible to make a panel have it´s own window?
meaning, it´s just a floating Panel, which i can move around if i want to, like a normal panel without a form.

I will be using it to display images, and i want to be able to draw on it from a thread (like i can with any panel).

I am guessing it should be possible, but can´t find any concrete examples on it.

I have my own Panel Class if that helps anything.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
namespace VoiceChat
{
    public class MyDisplay : Panel
    {

            public MyDisplay()
            {
                 this.DoubleBuffered = false;
                 this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.None;
                this.UpdateStyles();

            }

        }
    }
```

Though for some reason, Visual Studio want´s to make a Design code for this, if you know how to prevent that, please tell.

Well not sure what more to write, i don´t have any examples myself, as i don´t know how to bring a panel outside the main form.

Comment: do you need to have a Multiple of those "floting panels" or the main window to be a floating panel ?

Comment: I would prefer to have a panel that is like a window. Meaning, i have my form. where well buttons and all are. Then to display pictures, i will have that panel open up.